# IBOutlet declarations?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have seen the code below written 3 different ways (with regards to IBOutlet) Does it matter, I would say adding IBOutlet to both the declaration and the @property was more concise.

JUST PROPERTY:

```
@class SwitchViewController;

@interface iPhone_switcherAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    SwitchViewController *switchViewController;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SwitchViewController *switchViewController;
@end
```

JUST DECLARATION:

```
@class SwitchViewController;

@interface iPhone_switcherAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet SwitchViewController *switchViewController;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic, retain) SwitchViewController *switchViewController;
@end
```

BOTH:

```
@class SwitchViewController;

@interface iPhone_switcherAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet SwitchViewController *switchViewController;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SwitchViewController *switchViewController;
@end
```

cheers gary

Comment: @fuzzygoat: +1 Had the same question in mind, and here it was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should not matter. With the 10.6 64-bit SDK you can also write the property without the ivar:

```
@class SwitchViewController;

@interface iPhone_switcherAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SwitchViewController *switchViewController;
@end
```

Answer (score 11):

`IBOutlet` does only matter to InterfaceBuilder. For the compiler, UINibDeclarations.h `#define`s it to nothing.

InterfaceBuilder takes `IBOutlet` as a hint from the header file to list the available outlets for the class. If you wire up an object to an `IBOutlet`, no matter whether it is defined as a property or instance variable, this information is written into the nib.

When loading the nib, the loader tries to find the best possible way to setup the connection: First it tries to find a setter method with an appropriate name. If no such setter is found, it falls back to setting the instance variable directly, which is poor style, because memory management is not clear this way.

All your proposed examples have a property (and, of course, a setter method) of the right name. So in each case, the loader would use the setter method, no matter where the `IBOutlet` tag stands: There’s no difference between your examples, neither in the nib, nor in the way code is executed.

The best style would be to put the `IBOutlet` tag into the property definition.

Answer (score 3):

The current style in Apple's example code puts the IBOutlet in the property declaration. For consistency, that's probably the best place to throw it.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this way (without any property declaration):

```
@class SwitchViewController;

@interface iPhone_switcherAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet SwitchViewController *switchViewController;
}

@end
```

What about this?

Comment: Like Nikolai said further up, this would cause the Nib loader to set the instance variable directly, without going through a setter method, which means your class is no longer managing the memory of these variables (your code never "retains" it). Create property accessors to make sure the instances are properly retained and released.

Comment: Is this last comment still up to date with ARC?