# Read-only outlet?

Tags: objective-c, properties, readonly, setter, iboutlet

Let's say I have a class. I would like to declare a property in the following way:

1. From outside of the class it should be read-only *if accessed programmatically*;
2. It should be possible to set the value *from the Interface Builder* using an outlet;
3. (From inside the class it should be writable, but I know how to do it).

The "solution" I came up with is to write a one-time setter:

```
- (void) setA: (ClassA *)a {
    if (aHaveBeenSet)
        return;
    else {
        // do what a setter have to do
        aHaveBeenSet == YES;
    }
}
```

But this setter still can be called from the code (though only once in effect), so it's not quite a solution.

Another way is to mark the ivar as IBOutlet and make the property `readonly` like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
     IBOutlet ClassA *a;
}
@property (readonly) ClassA *a;
@end
```

But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206940/iboutlet-declarations/2207016#2207016), it's a poor style and makes memory management unclear.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I *think* the NIB loading mechanism checks for a setter method only when instantiating a .nib file at runtime.  So that means you could declare your public property as readonly but write a "private" setter in your .m file:

```
// MyClass.h
@property (readonly, retain) IBOutlet ClassA *a;
```

---

```
// MyClass.m
@interface MyClass ()
@property (readwrite, retain) ClassA *a;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize a;
...
@end
```

Comment: For more info on class extensions see [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2).

Comment: Is this supposed to mean that the nib-loading code will do something like `if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(setA:)]) [obj setA:a]`? If so, will the condition evaluate to `YES` despite the setter is not declared publicly?

Comment: First question: I don't know for sure, but I suspect yes.  Second question: definitely yes.